How to connect Drupal 10 site to Drupal 7 database?
I'm trying to migrate Drupal 7 to 10, I've installed both the sites locally in Docker, now I'm trying to add Drupal 7 database credentials in Drupal 10 settings.php file, but the connection is not establishing. Please provide any solutions.
Is it a genuine method if I import drupal 7 database to drupal 10 site as a second database and then add the imported database credentials to drupal 10 settings.php, I've tried this method and is successful.

You can connect to different database using this guide https://acquia.my.site.com/s/article/360041440113-Connecting-a-Drupal-application-to-multiple-Databases
